# Programmatical error handling in a resteasy restful application

Tags: java, json, jboss, resteasy

I have a restful web-service application that uses JSON and is deployed on a JBosss 6 EA server, which, in turn,  uses resteasy framework. The resteasy framework validates each user request for me and sends back an error message to the client if the request data is erroneous. Also, resteasy sets the HTTP Status code to 400, which is not what I want.

For example, I have defined in my application the enumeration MandantCode, which has three possible values (UNIQA, SLV, VVD) and is part of the request object. If I test my application by providing MandantCode a none-existing value XXX like this:

```
        "mandant" : { 
            "code": "XXX" 
        },
```

I recieve the following error message:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 400 - org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of at.uniqa.slsi.svc.model.Mandant$MandantCode from String value 'XXX': value not one of declared Enum instance names at [Source:....
```

Is there any way to programmatically validate the user request by providing custom error message for each invalid field? I would like to send the client back a legitimate HTTP 200 status code plus some JSON content structure describing the nature of the error.

Thank you and br: Alex

Comment: "I would like to send the client back a legitimate HTTP 200 status code"...no, in a RESTful design, a 400 "Bad Request" response is exactly what you should be sending back when a validation error like this occurs. If you send a 200, the client will think the request succeeded. You can still provide a more friendly error message in the response body though, in any format you choose. How you do that in jboss specifically I'm not sure, sorry (I'm not a Java expert, just came to the question via the JSON tag).

Comment: @ADyson, OK thank you very much. But to be able to provide a friendly error message I need to configure the resteasy framework not to perform the validation compeletely instead of me. So, I need some way to configure it.